# How to delete a refered Id from a schema that isn't populated (mongoose)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have a parent-schema and a child-schema that looks something like this:

```
parent{
       parent_id: .... ,
       name: {type: string} 
       child: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                ref: 'Child'}
}
child{
     child_id:...
     name: {type:string}
}
```

And now I delete child with child_id = X .

But I still have a reference of the child_id = X in my parents schema.

Q: Is there a way to delete all references that arent't populated?

edit: parent has more then 1 child so like:

```
parent{
   parent_id: .... ,
   name: {type: string} 
   child: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'Child'}]
}
```

Comment: You need to delete the child_id from the parent's collection separately

Comment: @PuneetSingh is there a quick way to do that if the child has more parents?

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are more parents of a child, after deleting the record from child collection, $unset the child from the parent collection, as shown in below query

```
Parent.updateMany(
   { child: child_id },
   { $unset: { child: "" } }
)
```

If a parent has more than one children in an array then use below query

```
Parent.updateMany(
   {  },
   { $pull: { child: child_id } }
)
```

**Remember child_id should be in ObjectId(..) format if needed**

Comment: Yes you are right when you are calling it async you need to add exec